# Checking if a boost timed thread has completed

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

I have been reading the boost thread documentation, and cannot find an example of what I need.

I need to run a method in a timed thread, and if it has not completed within a number of milliseconds,
then raise a timeout error.

So I have a method called invokeWithTimeOut() that looks like this:

```
// Method to invoke a request with a timeout.
bool devices::server::CDeviceServer::invokeWithTimeout(CDeviceClientRequest&  request,
                                                       CDeviceServerResponse& response)
{
   // Retrieve the timeout from the device.
   int timeout = getTimeout();
   timeout += 100; // Add 100ms to cover invocation time.

   // TODO: insert code here.

   // Invoke the request on the device.
   invoke(request, response);

   // Return success.
   return true;
}
```

I need to call invoke(request, response), and if it has not completed within timeout, the method needs to return false.

Can someone supple a quick boost::thread example of how to do this please.

**Note:** The timeout is in milliseconds. Both getTimeout() and invoke() are pure-virtual functions, that have been implemented on the device sub-classes.

Comment: What is invoke() here?  That doesn't seem like a Boost function.

Comment: Invoke is a pure virtual method on the class, like getTimeout() which will call the function on the device (sub) class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution: Launch `invoke` in a separate thread and use a future to indicate when invoke finishes:

```
boost::promise<void> p;
boost::future<void> f = p.get_future();
boost::thread t([&]() { invoke(request, response); p.set_value(); });
bool did_finish = (f.wait_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(timeout)) == boost::future_status::ready)
```

`did_finish` will be `true` if and only if the invoke finished before the timeout.

The interesting question is what to do if that is *not* the case. You still need to shutdown the thread `t` gracefully, so you will need some mechanism to cancel the pending invoke and do a proper `join` before destroying the thread. While in theory you could simply `detach` the thread, that is a very bad idea in practice as you lose all means of interacting with the thread and could for example end up with hundreds of deadlocked threads without noticing.

Comment: Is there a version of this that does not use boost::chrono? We have the boost::datetime available.

Comment: Also I am getting promise is not a member of boost, as a compiler error.

Comment: @MarcusMacWilliam Which version of Boost are you using? The datetime versions for the wait functions are deprecated and will be removed with Boost 1.55.

Comment: Added boost/thread/future.hpp to my pre-compiled headers. :-)

Comment: OK after including future.hpp, the errors about promise go away, but I am still getting future is not a member of boost.

Comment: @MarcusMacWilliam The `unique_future` from 1.51 is more or less the same as the `future` in the current version, so that change is fine. If using Chrono is not an option, you can just do a `timed_wait` on the future instead which uses datetime (although you will have to change that again if you upgrade Boost in the future).